# Model with Hibernate to Query by Contact Details in Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, relation

I would like to be able to query for an employee by the contact details.
Here is my model.

You can assume that I have the controller working.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }
}

public abstract class PersonalInformation extends BaseEntity {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String gender;
}


public abstract class Person extends PersonalInformation implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String alias;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String gender;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contact contact;

}

public class Owner extends Person implements Serializable {
}

public class Contact extends BaseEntity {
    private String emailAddress;
    private String mobileTelNo;
    private String homeTelNo;
    private String workTelNo;
}
```

This is what I tried, thinking that the persistence will be both ways, wo when I would build a controller, I could build the response to include either the owner or the employee or other entity that I might have in my system of contacts

```
public class Contact extends BaseEntity {
    private String emailAddress;
    private String mobileTelNo;
    private String homeTelNo;
    private String workTelNo;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Owner owner;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Employee employee;
}
```

The relation between contact and owner or any other entity that would have a contact is one to one.

Could someone help me map my entities one to another, so that data is persisted?
Is what I want to do a good practice, or is there a better way?

Desired output when querying by the email:

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/v1/contact/email/jow.doe@stackoverflow.com

{
              "firstName": "Joe",
              "lastName": "Doe",
              "middleName": "None",
              "alias": "JD",
              "dateOfBirth": "2000-02-12",
              "gender": "male",
              "contact": {
                  "emailAddress": "joe.doe@stackoverflow.com"

              }
          }
```

Note: please ignore if I missed any data in the output that is in the pojos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO `Contact` should not have any mappings to `Owner` or `Employee`. If you don't need it, don't map it. You can query the data by using a HQL query like `FROM Owner o JOIN o.contact c WHERE c.emailAddress = :email`.

Comment: Are you saying that because it is one to one, i could put the fields in Person and then the query would become easier to be handled?
can you point me to an example of the query you wrote down?

What I was thinking in the mean time, was to query the Contact table by email, get the ID of that record and query the Employee table by the Contact id which I received from the first query

Comment: "Are you saying that because it is one to one, i could put the fields in Person and then the query would become easier to be handled?" More or less, yeah. What kind of example do you need? I wrote the query which should work with your model.

Comment: I believe that is an example in SQL. Can I use it with SpringBoot? Sorry, pretty noob with Spring and hibernate.
I wonder what value could there be to keep that one to one table at this stage. Is there a particular requirement that you could think of?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what your requirements are. There sure is some use case where this could be interesting to have. Anyway, the HQL example I gave you should be enough to get you going. I would recommend you buy a book or go through some tutorials on JPA/Hibernate though to fully understand what is happening.

Comment: thank you. do you recommend any good tutorials/book?

Comment: The official Oracle documentation(https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) is ok to get started. Then there a few more articles here: https://www.baeldung.com/learn-jpa-hibernate I personally like the JPA book written by Mike Keith but the one from Joseph Ottinger should be pretty good as well as far as I heard.